# How to display the five last rows in a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to write HTML code that displays the last five rows from the database,

I have code which shows the last row, but I want to have the last five rows.

My code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "refd-2");
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM last ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 1");
$print_data = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);

echo $print_data[1];
echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last 5 results from DB if you specify `LIMIT 5`.

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","refd-2");
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM last ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 5");

// Get all rows at once as an array of rows
$rows = $result->fetch_all();
print_r($rows);
// or use foreach loop
foreach($rows as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

The `fetch_all()` method can be skipped if not needed and you can loop directly on the results.

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "refd-2");
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM last ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 5");
while($print_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

echo $print_data["row"]; 
// here you will change the name "row" to your database row name
echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change LIMIT 1 with LIMIT 5 and fetch your resultset.

```
 <?php
//database connectivity
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","refd-2") or die(mysqli_error());
//select  values from empInfo table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM last ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 5'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why have you added `die(mysqli_error())`? Enable MySQLi exceptions to see any potential problems instated.

Comment: This code still would not show last 5 rows. It would only show the 5th last row.

Comment: You also have an extra `'` in the SQL, which will be syntax error

Comment: `mysqli_error()` needs connection as an argument to work, but then again it is not needed if you have the errors enabled properly.